# Can not import name locked_file

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-client

I'm trying to use gsutil on my machine but I can't, this is the error:

```
cannot import name locked_file
```

I'm using linux, python 2.7, gsutil 4.20 and oauth2client 4.0

This is the error traceback:

```
# gsutil 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python-exec/python2.7/gsutil", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('gsutil==4.20', 'console_scripts', 'gsutil')()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 
561, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 
2627, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 
2287, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 
2293, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gslib/__main__.py", line 53, in 
<module>
from gslib import wildcard_iterator
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gslib/wildcard_iterator.py", 
line 37, in <module>
from gslib.third_party.storage_apitools import storage_v1_messages as 
apitools_messages
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-
packages/gslib/third_party/storage_apitools/storage_v1_messages.py", line 
22, in <module>
from apitools.base.py import encoding
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/__init__.py", 
line 22, in <module>
from apitools.base.py.credentials_lib import *
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-
packages/apitools/base/py/credentials_lib.py", line 50, in <module>
from oauth2client import locked_file
ImportError: cannot import name locked_file
```

And this is the installed packages:

```
[I] net-misc/gsutil
 Available versions:  ~3.42 ~4.19 (~)4.20 {PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7"}
 Installed versions:  4.20

[I] dev-python/oauth2client
 Available versions:  1.5.2^t 2.0.1^t ~2.2.0^t (~)4.0.0^t {test PYTHON_TARGETS="pypy python2_7 python3_4 python3_5 python3_6"}
 Installed versions:  4.0.0^t
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here - works for me:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/442
(downgrade oauth2client to 2.2.0)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)